# Rails 3 step-by-step form with registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am looking for the best way to create wizard with registration on my site.

I would like to show a form for adding things and at the same time register user.
For example, I need a form with some inputs for content and at the bottom, before "submit" button, inputs requires credentials (email, name, password) and saves content as this new user.

Comment: Start with [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms). You'll have to adjust some things to the Rails 3 way of doing things, but it should be a good start.

Comment: Take a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or something similar and then the add extra fields you need to signup form.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and railscasts (which shows how to act with this gem): [first](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) and [second](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)